# Why new object's attribute refers to the same attribute from previous objects?

Tags: python, object, attributes

I am using the following code to create a list of objects. Each object has an attribute. Each time an object is created, an `init` method is called to give it initial values, then new values are stored in the attribute.

```
class Obj():
    a = []

    def init(self):
        for i in range(2):
            self.a.insert(i, 0)


# Main
object_list = []

for i in range(5):
    if i == 0:
        aux = Obj()
        aux.init()    
    else:
        object_list.append(aux)
        aux = Obj()
        aux.init()       

    for j in range(2): 
        aux.a[j] = random.randint(0,50)

for i in range(len(object_list)):
    print object_list[i].a
```

The expected output would be something like this, where the printed attributes are of length 2:

```
[21, 9]
[3, 43]
[1, 33]
[5, 12]
```

However I am getting something like:

```
[37, 15, 26, 9, 5, 16, 15, 16, 42, 31]
[37, 15, 26, 9, 5, 16, 15, 16, 42, 31]
[37, 15, 26, 9, 5, 16, 15, 16, 42, 31]
[37, 15, 26, 9, 5, 16, 15, 16, 42, 31]
```

I know that the problem is that the attribute `a` of a newly created object points to the attribute `a` of the previous one, thus I have only one `a` attribute for all objects.

Why creating a new object does not mean creating a different attribute instead a reference to previous object's attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `a = []` is a class attribute and therefore will be shared with all the objects that you create for that class. if you have an `__init__` method and you put your `a = []` in there like this:

```
class Obj():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = []
```

then you won't have the problem

Answer (score 2):

You get this behavior because `a = []` makes `a` a class attribute and not an instance attribute.

If you will create a proper `__init__` method and change it to `self.a = []` you will get the expected behavior.